# Tab Page isn't Changing in Oracle Forms

Tags: forms, oracle

I have got five tabs which is changing with radio button in oracle  forms page.When i was debugging this code; while radio button is changing first 3 tabs is come but last 2 tabs not come.

I wrote this alert `x:=msgbox('al_bilgi', 'type - '||:BL_CTRL.rd_sito);` in "when-radio-changed" trigger to see which parameter types came and see first 3 parameters came but the others not.

How can i get these tabs ?

Comment: what are those parameters? what exactly is your problem? tabs aren't showing?

Comment: While I am changing radio button, tabs aren't change yeap.  @pablomatico

Comment: I didn't get any error about this problem.While the form was running, all tabs are coming but  last 2 tabs not change with radio button 's change. To see forms type, I added " msgbox" and when examined it first 3 tabs 's form type was came true; but last 2 type is coming  3th record type.@pablomatico

Comment: we would need to se the trigger code at least @xsentius

Comment: I solved this problem changing acces key in property palette.Thank you @pablomatico